# How to make sure the the saved document fits the schema in MongoDB?

Tags: mongoose, mean-stack

I have a MEAN app and I occasionally change the schema of the user document in MongoDB.

When I save a new document to the collection, I would like for the saved document to fit the schema exactly, otherwise raise an exception, is it possible?

Currently I can save partial document or even worse, try to save some non existing fields (in the schema) which MongoDB ignores.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Basically, Schema is the blueprint of a collection.  Each schema maps to a MongoDB collection and defines the shape of the documents within that collection.

Now come to your issue

**1: Can save partial document** : If you do not want to save partial document you have to mark all fields as required in document.It will throw an error if you send partial document

**2: try to save some non existing fields** : As you already written mongoose schema ignores the non existing fields But if you want an error to be thrown if client send some unwanted data then you have to handle this on your route.For that i will recommend you to use a library called [tv4](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tv4)

And also if u want to handle both points then also go for [tv4](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tv4)

Comment: Thanks. If I want all of my fields to be required, should I add it to all of them? I plan on doing it in unit tests and not in operational so I can go  bit crazy here... About tv4.validate(data, schema), Do you know what the arguments are? can it get mongoose schema and JSON as data?

Comment: By default every field in mongoose schema is optional. for making all fields u have to add required:true in each field .No tv4 has its own way of defining schema most of bit similar to mongoose schema i used this in my application in route level before making call to my db in this way i restrict client side unwanted data .  and yes JSON as data

Comment: So you have to have a schema for tv4 and a schema for Mongo?

Comment: Yes, i told u tv4 is used for route level checking and mongoose schema is a blueprint for database